# Oracle DB Set operators to count duplicate fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to use (union/intersect/minus) to count how many times primary key ACNUM is inside these tables.

I've tried multiple ways of using the SET operator but cannot seem to figure it out.

Even something like this doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT results.ACNUM, COUNT(results.books), COUNT(results.interests)
FROM (
 SELECT ACNUM FROM ACADEMIC A
 UNION
 SELECT COUNT(PANUM) as books FROM AUTHOR B
 UNION
 SELECT COUNT(FIELDNUM) as interests FROM INTEREST C
) results;
```

Basically, I need to convert this query (which works) to the query above, where I use the set operator.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACNUM
FROM ACADEMIC A
WHERE
  (SELECT COUNT(PANUM)
  FROM AUTHOR
  WHERE ACNUM = A.ACNUM) < 5
AND
  (SELECT COUNT(FIELDNUM)
  FROM INTEREST
  WHERE ACNUM = A.ACNUM) > 3;
```

Comment: Your requirements so far don't seem to make much sense. Why do you want to enforce using set operations?

Comment: That is exactly how I feel Lukas. This is the question that tells me to use a set operator: "Use a Set operator to create a list of academics who have written or co-written less than 5 papers and also have greater than 3 interests. List their academic number in
the output."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you insist on using set operators, but INTERSECT will return the expected result:

```
SELECT ACNUM
FROM ACADEMIC A

INTERSECT

SELECT ACNUM
FROM AUTHOR
GROUP BY ACNUM 
HAVING COUNT(PANUM) < 5

INTERSECT

SELECT ACNUM
FROM INTEREST
GROUP BY ACNUM 
HAVING COUNT(FIELDNUM) > 3;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Both intersects return nothing. My author table is set up with 2 keys: ACNUM and PANUM, while my interest table is set up with ACNUM, FIELDNUM and DESCRIP

Comment: This query is an exact translation of your original query. If it doesn't return the expected result your query and/or your description is wrong....

Answer (score 0):

You have used **UNION** query in wrong manner because the inner query in Ist query is resulting only one column and you are taking three columns from that.

You can use join here, like this :

```
 select a.ACNUM, count(ar.PANUM), count(i.FIELDNUM)

 from ACADEMIC a join AUTHOR ar on a.ACNUM=ar.ACNUM
     join INTEREST i on a.ACNUM=i.ACNUM

 group by a.ACNUM 
 having count(ar.PANUM)<5 and count(i.FIELDNUM)>3;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to return any results, this is probably to do with the fact that I don't actually have a "count" under 5, I have 0 matching keys inside that table.

Comment: But for you If second query is working then this should also work as you have used ACNUM field to match the records.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT X.ACNUM, Y.books, Z.interests
 FROM (
 (SELECT ACNUM FROM ACADEMIC A)X
 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT COUNT(PANUM) as books FROM AUTHOR B)Y
 ON X.ACNUM=Y.ACNUM
 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT COUNT(FIELDNUM) as interests FROM INTEREST C)Z
 ON X.ACNUM=Z.ACNUM ) WHERE Y.books<5 and Z.interests>3;
```